# SQL Transpose Columns into Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I've been trying to transpose this;

```
**ProjectNum    PillarID    BusinessPillar**
95329           29          Pillar29
95329           1           Pillar1
95354           1           Pillar1
95354           4           Pillar4
95354           7           Pillar7
```

Into this;

```
**ProjectNum    Pillars**
95329           Pillar1, Pillar29
95354           Pillar1, Pillar4, Pillar7
```

I have looked at using pivot/unpivot and I've gotten this far

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PillarID) 
                from dbo.MyTable
                group by BusinessPillar, PillarID
                order by PillarID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
set @query = N'SELECT ProjectNum, ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select ProjectNum, PillarID, BusinessPillar
            from dbo.MyTable
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(BusinessPillar)
            for PillarID in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

However I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to combine all of the pivoted results into a single, comma separated column like in my desired example.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: please add the name of DB as tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the result that you want:

```
SELECT ProjectNum, STUFF(
     (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + BusinessPillar
      FROM Test
      WHERE ProjectNum = t.ProjectNum
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS Pillars
      FROM Test as t
      GROUP BY ProjectNum
```

Here's the SQL Fiddle link :
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/614bb/15)

Answer (score 0):

Try using LISTAGG:

```
SELECT ProjectNum, LISTAGG(BusinessPillar, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BusinessPillar) AS PILLARS
      FROM Test
      GROUP BY ProjectNum
```

[More info on LISTAGG](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)